# Метод View.isActivated

Tags: android

Что значит состояние активации представления ("activation state of the view")?

Я читала описание методов [isActivated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isActivated()):

> Indicates the activation state of this view.

и [setActivated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setActivated())

> Changes the activated state of this view. A view can be activated or
>   not. Note that activation is not the same as selection. Selection is a
>   transient property, representing the view (hierarchy) the user is
>   currently interacting with. Activation is a longer-term state that the
>   user can move views in and out of. For example, in a list view with
>   single or multiple selection enabled, the views in the current
>   selection set are activated. (Um, yeah, we are deeply sorry about the
>   terminology here.) The activated state is propagated down to children
>   of the view it is set on.

но всё равно не понятно, что значит, когда представление активировано или нет...

Answer (score 2):

`View.isActivated`

вернет `true`, если вьюшка используется, когда она активирована как постоянный выбор (например, чтобы «выделить» ранее выбранный элемент списка в режиме постоянной навигации)

вернет `false` если вьюшка используется, когда объект не активирован

Примером можно служить, например, подгруппа (ветвь) списка-дерева. Когда на нее нажимаешь она выделяется другим цветом и обозначает, что она открыта.

Свойство `android:state_activated` можно заюзать в селекторе.. Так же, как `state_pressed` или `state_focused`

Comment: а что значит "в режиме постоянной навигации"?

Comment: Мне вообще кажется, что `activated` скоро будет `deprecated`. `ListView` изнутри вызывает у айтемов метод `setSelected(true)`, тем самым задействовывает `state_selected` в селекторе айтема. **Нигде** я не сталкивался, чтобы приходилось указывать `state_activated`. Ну а по вопросу вашему.. Сам не понял толком, это перевод одного из вопросов на enSO

Comment: Кстати, вот на гитхабе пример, где он используется https://github.com/ag12/Rabbit-Android/blob/3c029fc1a788104eba83b0ade1e80882912e3727/app/src/main/res/drawable/item_selector.xml

Comment: А вот использование в коде https://github.com/sirchip/spotifystreamer/blob/e48a36a2fa302c7af93aa14f63fe65256dc29275/app/src/main/java/io/poundcode/spotifystreamer/base/SelectableRecyclerView.java про что я и говорил.